# Map didn't render in 3d.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a project that is about data visualization, however I am encountering problems. I need to render a map of a country (Brazil) using d3.js. When I move the mouse through the state it should appear the acronym of the state with the income per capita. In addition each state must be in a color tint (in the case I chose green) based on per capita income. I am sending my code because I am not getting my map to render the correct colors and are not showing the acronym and the income. If anyone can help, I appreciate it.

Here´s [a link of the code](https://gist.github.com/fabrimatt/d0a947ab4cec3aff3b740351f2a99039)

Comment: I see a couple things that are not correct -- when you are trying to get the color, the lookup is using `d.id` which is not defined in your csv data. Instead, the first column is called "UF". Also, when building the `<title>` element, you are attempting to show the `d.value` string from your geojson data, which probably does not exist in those county objects.

Comment: HI SteveR. I did the changes that you said. The map is now render but with no color and the tooltip didn't show the value and the UF that came from renda_per_capita.tsv. Here the  code https://gist.github.com/fabrimatt/d0a947ab4cec3aff3b740351f2a99039

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems with the code that builds each country's path -- try updating this section:

```
svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(br, br.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "states")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(valueByÚF.get(d.UF)); })
      .attr("d", path)
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return "UF: "+ d.UF; });
```

Honestly, I didn't check to see if the quantize scale is the right one to use for your data, so you may want to try other scales...

Comment: Hi SteveR. I did the changes that you said, and folowwing others tutorials in the web I changed others things and now is working. Here the code https://gist.github.com/fabrimatt/d0a947ab4cec3aff3b740351f2a99039         Thanks for the help